# What is $\int_{0}^1\ln(\sin(x)) dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I can calculate the integral on $[0,\pi/2]$ interval, but that solution cant be applied here because it uses $\sin(\pi/2 - x)=\cos x$ and the rule $$\int_{a}^b f(x)dx=\int_{a}^b f(a+b-x) dx$$ which here would turn into $\sin(1-x)$ which is useless. I'd be grateful if anyone could help. (Also i saw some general solutions involving i, i don't know complex integration so please don't go down that route)

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this integral can be calculated in terms of elementary functions? That's usually not the case...

Comment: CAS says: $-\ln (2)-\frac{1}{2} \Im\left(\text{Li}_2\left(e^{2 i}\right)\right)$

Comment: Use series expansion and termwise integration.

Comment: Where did you encounter a _need_ to evaluate this? If you were asked to, there's a surprisingly good chance it's a misprint for $\int_0^1\ln\sin(\pi x)dx$.

Comment: i asked a teacher and he said i could estimate it , saying it is less than $pi(1-ln(sin(1)))$ . i tried to look for a function f that is bigger than ln(sin(x)) and we can integrate easily , but couldnt come up with something that didnt mess up the bound.

Comment: If you just want to know why $\int_0^1\ln\sin xdx<\pi(1-\ln\sin 1)$, it's enough to note the LHS is negative.

Comment: i made a slight mistake , sorry. i meant $$- \int_{0}^1 ln(sin(x)) \leq \pi (1-ln sin 1)$$.

Comment: In fact you can drop that factor of $\pi$, because $1.06<1.17$.

Comment: I've updated my answer to prove the desired inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Let me introduce the *polylogarithm*$$\operatorname{Li}_s(z):=\sum_{n\ge1}z^nn^{-s}$$(technically we analytically continue the RHS, but I don't think you want that kind of complex-analytic pedantry right now). In particular, $\frac{d}{dz}\operatorname{Li}_2(z)=-z^{-1}\ln(1-z)$ so$$\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{2ix})=-2i\ln(1-e^{2ix})=-2i\ln\sin x+2x-\color{blue}{2i\ln(-2i)}.$$Applying $\frac{-1}{2i}\int dx$,$$\int\ln\sin xdx=\frac{i}{2}\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{2ix})-x^2\right)+\color{blue}{2i\ln(-2i)}x+C.$$I'll leave you to ponder what the blue coefficient should be, i.e. which branch of the complex logarithm it needs.

As @jjagmath noted, it's highly unlikely the $\int_0^1$ result has a closed form, except for what the above indefinite integral implies. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+ln%28sin+x%29+from+0+to+1) can do no better, although at least it will help you test your thoughts about the blue value. The result is in line with @MariuszIwaniuk comment.

Edit: we can prove $\int_0^1(-\ln\sin x)dx<1-\sin1$ or equivalently $\int_0^1\left(-\ln\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)dx<-\sin1$ by noting the latter integrand increases from $0$ at $x=0$ to $-\ln\sin1$ at $x=1$, so the latter integral has upper bound $\int_0^1(-\ln\sin1)dx=-\ln\sin1$.

Comment: thank you for this, it's nice. but could you think of any function that is less than ln(sin(x)) and can be integrated easily? its integration on the interval [0,1] is $$\pi (ln(sin(1))-1)$$ apparently.